# Amazon API Gateway authorization AWS_IAM

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

What does it means `AWS_IAM` as Authorization model in Amazon API Gateway?

[image]

If I test the Lambda inside the AWS console it works and prints "Hello World", but if I use the endpoint URL and open it inside another browser's tab it say `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}` how can I get this authentication token?

Answer (score 19):

## Create a new IAM user

Go to AWS **IAM** and create a new user with **programmatic access** for accessing your API Gateway. Then attach a policy with enough permissions `(AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess)` to the user/group to be able to access your API Gateway endpoint. Once you get through all the steps, you will be presented with a key/secret for your new user.

## Make an API request with AWS Signature using Postman

Now, to simplify things, install [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and then use the `Authorization` tab in your request page, to select `AWS Signature`:

[image: Postman-AWS-Signature]

Fill in `AccessKey` / `SecretKey` for your new user, `AWS Region` in which you operate (e.g., `us-west-1`) and click the `Update Request` button.
At that point Postman will fill in the necessary Headers for your request and you can make authorized requests to your API Gateway.

Comment: Thanks, I hope that this solution would integrate with OpenID Connect. I need to search another solution :)

Comment: For that you should look into a custom authorizer Lambda function. Your function can then authenticate against any 3rd-party you want, then results can be cached for a desired amount of time in your API Gateway.

Comment: So I can't do this with Enhanced (simplified) workflow? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html

Comment: How to implement the same on a static webpage instead of using Postman?

Comment: Static website can't use AWS secrets. You want to use JWT tokens from some identity provider (such as Auth0) that the user receives in exchange for their login/password. JWT tokens sent from user's browser to your gateway, will then be validated by a Custom Authorizer for your API Gateway. Such Authorizer will then be a simple Lambda function that validates the token for you and lets user requests into your gateway.

Comment: this is not working for me. I'm getting error: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

Answer (score 9):

Repeating my answer from our forums:

AWS_IAM authentication means you must sign requests using AWS signature version for and AWS credentials. More details on Signature Version 4 [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html).

You may want to look at a tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to generate signatures for testing.

Comment: Thanks. In this way I always need access key and secret and there is no way to include openid connect to autheticate. Am I right? Should custom authorizer do the job?

Comment: Correct. You can use custom authorizer to support alternative authentication methods.

Comment: @BobKinney : How can i get the context authorizers data using AWS_IAM authentication ?? it gives me blank value. i am using lamda functiion in api gateway. but with AWS_IAM role i am not getting any value. can u please give your feedback on this?

Comment: @Bob Kinney How to implement the same on a static webpage instead of using Postman?

Answer (score 0):

To get the authentication token for cross account permission, I will assume that you have a role to assume or you can view [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-assume-role-cli/) how it works and how to get one.

In the tutorial above you can see a step assume role which has this command

aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/example-role" --role-session-name AWSCLI-Session

the response of this command will be similar to

```
{
"AssumedRoleUser": {
    "AssumedRoleId": "asdfa:AWSCLI-Session", 
    "Arn": "something"
}, 
"Credentials": {
    "SecretAccessKey": "key", 
    "SessionToken": "token", 
    "AccessKeyId": "key"
}
```

}

As shown in the @jaccus answer you can use the following value and send the request via postman

- SecretAccessKey
- SessionToken
- AccessKeyId